# sha1 + salt -> migrate from php to node.js

Tags: php, node.js

I got an existing working login system with php and mysql.
I want to migrate this to node.js. Is there a usefull solution with the same product for the code below? Or maybe its better to rewrite all including generate new password?

thanks in advance

```
/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }
```

and the use of the function:

```
public function getUserByNameAndPassword($name, $password) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $salt = $result['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and

```
public function storeUser($name, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    //more code ...
}
```

Comment: You read my thread? I want to get away from php and you tell me to use another PHP function?

Comment: I'm not telling you to use PHP functions, I'm warning you that your current setup is not safe. The guide tells you which hashing algorithms are safe to use, use their equivalent in NodeJS.

Comment: Any chance my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this native node library:

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

This will allow you to hash properly, and you can select from multiple engines for hashing.  Additionally, there are many crypto modules such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt.

With either of those you can reproduce that same php as javascript pretty easily.